# How can I Remove/Ignore '&&' condition in IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Let's say I've three POST variables

```
$one = $_POST['one'];
$two = $_POST['two'];
$three = $_POST['three'];
```

I've another list of variables to compare with the posted values.

say `$four, $five, $six`

So I don't need to compare the posted value with other variables, if posted variable has a value of 'All'

Ex: If none of the POST variables have 'All' value

```
if($one == $four && $two == $five && $three = $six)
{
//my code 
}
```

For example when `$_POST['two'] = 'All'` then the condition would looks follows

```
if($one == $four && $three = $six)
{
//my code.
}
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: think this will work - ($one == 'one' || $one == 'All') && ($two == 'two' || $two == 'All')  && ($three = 'three' || || $three == 'All')

Comment: @sgt I don't need to check if the variable  has 'All' value. the values of the variable would be anything. I just mentioned 'one','two','three' as an example. Sorry I think my question isn't clear

Comment: didnt get what you r asking.if the value could be anything the how can you check the condition?

Comment: @sgt Infact this is not the exact criteria I'm using in my project. I thought to make my post as simple as possible. That makes the confusion. I'm sorry I'll try to explain clearly. (I am going to edit my post) I was in hurry :(

Comment: do you want to ignore the condition if the value is 'All' or some other values will be considered?

Comment: @sgt I need to compare the three variable with other three. Just like $one with $four , $two with $five, $three with $six. For ex $one (posted value) = 'All' I don't need to compare this with $four.

Comment: then what is the problem of using or condition??

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
if(($one == 'one'||$one == 'All') && ($two == 'two'||$two == 'All') && ($three == 'three'||$three== 'All'))
{
//my code 
}
```

Because

```
A AND B = A whenever B is true
```

In this case the expressions in brackets will be (effectively) ignored if they are true.

Comment: Sorry, I know I wasn't clear. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if( ($one == $four || $one == 'All') && ($two == $five || $two == 'All') && ($three = $six || $three == 'All'))
{
//my code 
}
```

hope will give what you want.